# No internet access with Wireguard

Tags: 20.04, vpn, wireguard

I'm trying to configure VPN with wireguard.

My server config:

```
[Interface]
PrivateKey = <key>
Address = 10.0.0.1/24
ListenPort = 51830
PostUp = iptables -A FORWARD -i %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
PostDown = iptables -D FORWARD -i %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE

[Peer]
PublicKey = <key>
AllowedIPs = 10.0.0.2/32
```

Client config:

```
[Interface]
PrivateKey = <key>
Address = 10.0.0.2/32
DNS = 8.8.8.8

[Peer]
PublicKey = <key>
Endpoint = <my_host>:51830
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0
PersistentKeepalive = 20
```

When wireguard turns on, ping works. But I can't load any web pages. What I do wrong?

Comment: In the **client config** change the `Address = 10.0.0.2/32` to `../24`. Addresses in the `[Interface]` section should be masked to something less than 32.

Comment: @FedKad the same situation. Ping works, but internet doesn't

Comment: Did you complete step 4 in the following "how-to" for example? https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-wireguard-on-ubuntu-20-04